# How can I "preload" the Google Maps API in a FLEX 3.5 TabNavigator Tab?

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps, tabs, freeze, tabnavigator

I have a Flex 3.5 Air Application; The main window has, besides the header, a TabNavigator. In a Tab, I've put a Google Maps object. It works fine, except that it "loads" very slow and the whole application freezes ( not responding problem ).

Now I would like to fix that but don't really now how to implement one of these solutions:
1) Load the API before the whole application loads.
2) Load the API somehow async, when the tab is clicked. I don't really need a fancy preloader, it's enough that my app doesn't freeze.

Please note that I'm "110%" sure that it's the GoogleMaps's fault since the tab canvas is empty, and no other code is there [double checked that]. Also please note that the map only loads, then I call the setCenter method, so no other operations that could freeze it.

EDIT: I managed to determine that not the Api Object creation is slow, but the actual display of it on the GUI. Here's the line of code. ResellersMapClass only extends the Google Maps API class since I intend to add there extra functionality. But right now is clean.

```
this.map = new ResellersMapClass();
//between here
this.mapContainer.addChild( this.map  );
//and here
```

Now is there a way to preload this ? Or any other solution that will prevent the GUI from freezing.

Thanks,
Gabriel

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the API is loading slow. Could you elaborate a little bit on this? How long does it load? How's the project set up? Maybe you could show us some code?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Not the API is loading slow, the API call. There's really nothing to show. I just add the MXML code for Google Maps, as seen on the API Examples Pages ( fill in my key, and that's it ). I was just hoping that there is an async method to "load" a generic object, a method that won't freeze the whole app. Please don't get me wrong, I'm not paranoid about my code or something, it's just that I'm 99% sure it's a generic GMaps problem.

Comment: Was there a solution for this?

Comment: Not really. I set the API to load after half second, so my tab would display before the freeze, and noticed that on the release build the freeze was not complete, only on debug mode. pretty akward.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Yahoo! map API. I ended up just dropping it in a module and gave it a ProgressBar for the load. That should help with the async issues at least. If the problem is a heavy algorithm in the library, there is no way around that until flash rolls out true multi-threading (crosses fingers).